# Score in DOM not updating

Tags: javascript, html, dom, updating

Can't figure out why my score is not updating in the DOM. It updates correctly in the console when I print it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code below:

**------HTML-----**

```html
<header>
    <h1 id="score">$0</h1>
    <h1>Welcome To The Landscaper Game</h1>
    <img id="landscaper"src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQquSwF4xk5fT2J1P3aUWEEOTIdDI4m2p6Iew&usqp=CAU" alt="picture of gardner">
    <button class="buttons" id="start-game">Click to Start Game</button>
</header>
```

**-----Javascript----**

```
let userEarnings = 0;
let scoreboardDOMLocation = document.getElementById('score').innerText
console.log(scoreboardDOMLocation);

const teethEarnings = () => {
    scoreboardDOMLocation = (userEarnings += earnings.teeth);
    console.log('You clicked on teeth');
    console.log(scoreboardDOMLocation);
}

document.getElementById('teethPic').addEventListener('click',teethEarnings);
```

Comment: `scoreboardDOMLocation` is not a reference to the `.innerText` property of `#score`. It's just a variable with a string in it. Changing it's content doesn't change the DOM (`#score`).

Comment: I added a bit of code probably after you responded. scoreboardDOMLocation IS a reference to the .innerText of #score. Everything updates correctly in the console but not the DOM

Comment: No, it's not a reference to anything. It's just a variable that stores the string that the `.innerText` property returned.

Comment: OP, what you're actually doing on the second line where you initialize `scoreboardDomLocation` is creating a *copy* of `#score.innerText`. Within `teethEarnings()` you're only updating that copy of the value, not the value that gets rendered in the DOM.

Comment: You guys are awesome! Thanks for the help!!!!

Answer (score 2):

@Andreas is correct. You only stored the text of the h1 html-element but no
reference to the actual html-element. The code should look like this:

```js
let scoreboardDOMLocation = document.getElementById('score');

const teethEarnings = () => {
    scoreboardDOMLocation.innerHTML = (userEarnings += earnings.teeth);
    console.log('You clicked on teeth');
}

document.getElementById('teethPic').addEventListener('click',teethEarnings);
```